# grunt-bbb problems with jam

Tags: backbone.js, gruntjs

I have started recently with bbb and grunt-bbb and currently I have problems with the `bbb jam` option.

I have created a project with `bbb:init`, created a test module and right now I want to add dependencies to codemirror project. So I have added the sentence `"codemirror": "2.35.1"` to the dependencies section on the package.json file.

The problem is when I execute bbb jam upgrade I get the next error:

```
<WARN> Task "upgrade" not found. Use --force to continue. </WARN>

Aborted due to warnings.

Running "jam" task
Error: TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
    at Object.module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bbb/tasks/jam.js:52:10)
    at Object.task.registerTask.thisTask.fn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bbb/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:58:16)
    at Task.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bbb/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:343:36)
    at Task.start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bbb/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:359:5)
    at Object.grunt.tasks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bbb/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:143:8)
    at Object.module.exports [as cli] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bbb/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/cli.js:36:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bbb/bbb.js:98:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

But also I have jam installed and if I run it by hand jam upgrade it works fine.

After that last sentence the codemirror project has been downloaded and the vendor/jam/require.config.js file has been updated but the library is never loaded by "require.js".

Any ideas.
Thanks.

Comment: Finally I found it was a mistake using the tool in its current version but that there is an intention to make changes in future versions. See: https://github.com/backbone-boilerplate/grunt-bbb/issues/96